# How to get a full screenshot of a page that goes off screen?

Tags: arch-linux, software-rec, web, screenshot

I seem to remember that maybe it was in Chrome or somewhere else that one could right-click on a web page and get a full screenshot of the entirety of the page as though it would fit on the monitor properly without zooming out. With Firefox though I have found no such feature, I am running Arch Linux with GNOME 3.24.2 and Wayland, is there any way to do this? Maybe a Firefox add-on or some software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Firefox' Developer Tools as described at the [Mozilla Wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Taking_screenshots):

```
* Open the Developer Tools (Hamburger Menu -> Developer -> Toggle Tools)
* visit the Settings page
* find the section labeled "Available Toolbox Buttons"
* check the box labeled "Take a screenshot of the entire page"
```

Youcan now use the Screenshot button (a small camera) in the upper right of the Developer Tools to take a screenshot of any website.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally advice you to just try googling first. It's quite a trivial thing to find without asking it on U&L SE. And moreover it's not a *nix specific question.

But still, here you go: [ScreenGrub](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab-fix-version/?src=search)

This addon is what you were searching for.